# Managing multiple processes within a NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, child-process

Let's say I'd want to control (start/stop) several other NodeJS scripts from within one "main" NodeJS app. However, not necessarly NodeJS Scripts exclusively, but also simple bash scripts.

I'm  looking into the following solution, using `execa`

```js
// simplified

const managedProcesses = [];

async function Start (pkg) {
  const runningProcess = await execa(pkg.run_command, {
    cwd : pkg.path
  });
  return runningProcess;
}

async function Stop (pkg) {
  // somehow stop the child process
  return
}

const someProcess = await Start({
  run_command : 'node app.js',
  path : './path/to/my/script/'
});

// Keep Reference of process
managedProcesses.push(someProcess);
```

I first thought `pm2` would be a viable solution, but I guess this would only fit for NodeJS-only scripts.

#### What Problems could I run into using the approach above ?

#### Should I consider moving forward with this idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For node.js subprocesses there is the [cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) and I strongly recommend using this. For general subprocesses (e.g. bash scripts as you mentioned) you have to use `child_process` (-> execa). Communication between processes may then be accomplished via grpc. Your approach is fine, so you can consider moving forward with it.

Comment: Thanks for the details and for giving me courage :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go full with `pm2` for the time being, as they have an excellent [programmatic API](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/) - also (which I only just learned about) you can specify [different interpreters](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/#start-any-process-type) to run your script. So not only `node` apps are possible but also `bash`, `python`, `php` and so on - which is exactly what I am looking for.